# SQL query to pull ONLY data which contains range of records

Tags: sql

I need your help to write query with select statement to pull only claim IDs which contains code from this range: 99213, 99214, 99215, 99217.

So my results should be claim ID 1 (all lines) and claim ID 3 (all lines). Since claim ID 2 has codes which are outside of the range, i do not want that in my results.

```
Claim id    line #  code
1            1     99213
1            2     99214
1            3     99215
1            4     99217
2            1     99213
2            2     89557
2            3     36415
3            1     99215
3            2     99217
```

Result should be like this

```
Claim id    line #  code
1            1     99213
1            2     99214
1            3     99215
1            4     99217
3            1     99215
3            2     99217
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery to isolate `ClaimID`s that have `Code`s outside of your list of values.  Then rule them out of the main query with a `not in`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ClaimID NOT IN (
      SELECT ClaimID FROM Table WHERE Code NOT IN (99213,99214,99215,99217)
);
```